# Error in trying to access a file in the sub-folder of my current matlab folder

Tags: matlab, path

I am trying to read an excel file which is a sub-folder of my current Matlab folder. I am using the code below for that:

*readtable('\Reference data\Aircraft OOP.xlsx','Sheet','formerge');*

Where 'Reference data' is a folder in my current Matlab folder.
But I get the following error message when I run the code.

**Unable to open file 'C:\Reference data\Aircraft OOP.xlsx' as a workbook. Check that the file exists, read access is available, and the file is
a valid spreadsheet file.**

As you can see Matlab assumes that 'Reference data' directory is in C:/ instead.

I can solve this by simply using the whole path but this code will be used by different users and if the whole path is used each user will have to edit the above line before they run the code.

So I wanted to know how to set my current folder as the main folder instead of C:/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string

```
'\Reference data\Aircraft OOP.xlsx'
```

represents an *absolute* path, since it starts with `\`, the root directory of the drive.

To specify a *relative* path, remove the backslash:

```
'Reference data\Aircraft OOP.xlsx'
```

This path will be evaluated relative to the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below points before moving to the solution.

- Check whether the folder which contains the excel file to be read,
  really exists in the Matlab's workspace(Matlab's current folder) or not? If not then move the folder(which contains the excel file) to the Matlab's workspace(Matlab's current folder).
- Check for the folder name and file name spellings.

*If all is right then move to the below solution to the issue you are facing.*

Construct the full file path using the following line of code.

```
fullfilePath = fullfile(pwd, '\Reference data\Aircraft OOP.xlsx');
```

`pwd` in the above code is the command to access the path of current working directory of the Matlab.

Now you can use the readtable command to read the file.

```
readtable(fullfilePath,'Sheet','formerge');
```

Alternatively, you can also use the following line of code to correctly read the excel file.

```
readtable('.\Reference data\Aircraft OOP.xlsx','Sheet','formerge');
```

The dot( . ) in the beginning of file path tells the Matlab to search the folder a level up in current working directory of the Matlab.

Comment: By Matlab workspace I mean the Matlab's current directory which is accessible by the Matlab when an m file is executed. The person who asked the question has clearly mentioned that the folder which contains the excel file is in the Matlab's current folder(which means the current working directory of the Matlab).

Comment: The excel file is not in the current directory, it is in a folder which in turn is in the current directory. The folder which contains the excel file is not added to the Matlab's path that's why the error.